# UITableView Core Data Grouping and Relationships

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, core-data

I'm seeking some assistance with my very first iPhone app. The whole concept of Core Data so far is very overwhelming.

---

### Core Data Model:

[image: Core Data Model]

### Table View Code:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    //return 1;
    return [self.fetchedCoursesArray count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.

    return [self.fetchedRoundsArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"RoundsCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle  reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    }

    Rounds * rounds = [self.fetchedRoundsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Date: %@",rounds.date];
    //cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@",courses.city,courses.state];
    return cell;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    Courses * courses = [self.fetchedCoursesArray objectAtIndex:section];
    return courses.name;
}
```

---

### Table View Picture (Result of Code):

[image: Table View]

## The Problem...

The problem is that the grouping is not correct.. it displays the same two items for each group. The rounds need to be grouped according to each course name but I do not know how to accomplish this in code, so I've resorted to asking for help. I've done hours of research now.. lots of Stack Overflow questions, and different tutorials with no avail.

Would anyone be able to provide me with some direction?

## Update

Here are some logs of the arrays as they are loaded into the view:

```
2013-10-23 23:27:16.771 Test 2[1566:70b] COURSES: (null)
2013-10-23 23:27:16.772 Test 2[1566:70b] ROUNDS: (null)
2013-10-23 23:27:16.773 Test 2[1566:70b] COURSES: (null)
2013-10-23 23:27:16.773 Test 2[1566:70b] ROUNDS: (null)
2013-10-23 23:27:16.775 Test 2[1566:70b] COURSES: (
    "<Courses: 0x8ab99a0> (entity: Courses; id: 0x8ab8b40 <x-coredata://5B7FCAFF-4AFF-4DB9-AAE1-93F0B8D920E2/Courses/p1> ; data: {\n    city = Arlington;\n    holes = 18;\n    name = \"Jones Park\";\n    rounds = \"<relationship fault: 0x8c35a30 'rounds'>\";\n    state = TX;\n})",
    "<Courses: 0x8ab9c30> (entity: Courses; id: 0x8ab8b50 <x-coredata://5B7FCAFF-4AFF-4DB9-AAE1-93F0B8D920E2/Courses/p2> ; data: {\n    city = Arlington;\n    holes = 22;\n    name = \"Test Park\";\n    rounds = \"<relationship fault: 0x8c35b40 'rounds'>\";\n    state = TX;\n})"
)
2013-10-23 23:27:16.776 Test 2[1566:70b] ROUNDS: (
    "<Rounds: 0x8c352a0> (entity: Rounds; id: 0x8c345f0 <x-coredata://5B7FCAFF-4AFF-4DB9-AAE1-93F0B8D920E2/Rounds/p1> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<Rounds: 0x8c354c0> (entity: Rounds; id: 0x8c34600 <x-coredata://5B7FCAFF-4AFF-4DB9-AAE1-93F0B8D920E2/Rounds/p2> ; data: <fault>)"
)
```

I see there is a relationship issue.. but I don't think a relationship is necessary to group them in the way I need? Maybe it would make it easier though. Hope this helps..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using the same results whether the section is the first course or the second course. You probably need to drill down your data better.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"RoundsCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle  reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    }

    Courses * courses = [self.fetchedCoursesArray objectAtIndex:section];
    Rounds * rounds = [[courses.rounds allObjects] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Date: %@",rounds.date];
    return cell;
}
```

And you'd need to do something similar for `numberOfRowsInSection` too - just to ensure you're returning the right number of rows. It might be worth looking into `NSFetchedResultsController` too as it takes a lot of the headache out of dealing with Core Data in `UITableView`.

Comment: Thanks for your help! This is what I get with your code (I modified `objectAtIndex:section` to be `objectAtIndex:indexPath.section`. **http://cl.ly/S8AZ**
This is how I am creating those arrays: `self.fetchedRoundsArray = [appDelegate getAllRounds];
    self.fetchedCoursesArray = [appDelegate getAllCourses];` http://cl.ly/S890

Comment: Ok, what's the log output of `courses.rounds` ? Try `Rounds * rounds = [courses.rounds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`

Comment: Says `Property rounds not found on object of type Courses.`

Comment: Ok what did you name the relationship between your courses model and rounds?

Comment: Well I don't know if the first picture in the original question helps, but here is another.. http://cl.ly/S7kX

Comment: Yep. It should be ok as you've called it rounds. What does your Courses NSManagedObject class header look like? Should be called Courses.h

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39949/discussion-between-squarefrog-and-brandon)

Answer (score 1):

Because you return **[self.fetchedRoundsArray count]** in  numberOfRowsInSection method,
you have to return associated RoundsArray for course.

Please add log to print both fetched array.

Comment: I added the logs for you. I didn't really know where to put the code for the logs so I added two NSLog's into the **`numberOfSectionsInTableView`** method. I think it will suffice to at least see what the arrays contain. Let me know what you think. On a side note, would you be kind to upvote my question if you think it's worthy of one? I'd really like to get to 10 so I can post pictures as well!